# understanding java code Deconstruction patterns (JEP 405: Record Patterns & Array Patterns)

Tags: java

i have a code snippet from this document: [*JEP 405: Record Patterns & Array Patterns (Preview)*](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/405).

I am trying to understand this code and what it does basically in order to rewrite it in c (using union ) or java or sml for example or even pascal/kotlin.

Can anyone please explain for me what this piece of code means?

```
int eval(Expr n) {
    return switch(n) {
        case IntExpr(int i) -> i;
        case NegExpr(Expr n) -> -eval(n);
        case AddExpr(Expr left, Expr right) -> eval(left) + eval(right);
        case MulExpr(Expr left, Expr right) -> eval(left) * eval(right);
        default -> throw new IllegalArgumentException(n);
    };
}
```

i know it is doing kind of pattern matching with n , but what i didn't understand where did they get left and right from ?? do we get them with n ?
i am lost could someone help me

Comment: `case MulExpr(Expr left, Expr right)` declares two new variables `left` and `right` which are set to the corresponding record components in `MulExpr`'s definition.

Comment: but where do they get their values ? Is it transmitted from function eval ? and how !

Comment: The values come from the fields of the record.

Comment: what is the record here ? is it n ? the witch basically gets different n values that could be : IntExpr for example , so if n=IntExpr  then ... ?

Comment: The record is an Expr which has subtypes IntExpr, NegExpr, AddExpr, and MulExpr.

Comment: so an example of this would be that eval function would get an integer or an (x+y) or a negative number .. and  then the output is according to the above ?

Comment: that means if i want to write this in c i should write a function the switch over all of those cases ..

Comment: The MulExpr block is equivalent to `if (n instance of MulExpr) { MulExpr me = (MulExpr} n; Expr left = me.getLeft(); Expr right = me.getRight(); ... `

Comment: can i rewrite this function using java and instantof ? if yes how !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Expr` is a base class.
The switch matches it to a specific subclass and extracts parameters from the record.  Those parameters are used in the expression for the return value of the switch expression.

So if `n` is an instance of `IntExpr` the `int i` member of the record is returned.
If `n` is a `NegExpr` its `Expr n` member is passed recursively to the `eval` method and then the result is negated before it is returned.
Similarly when matching an `AddExpr` or `MulExpr` the `left` and `right` Expr members are used to recursively evaluate those expressions and return the sum or the product respectively.

So each case matches a specific type with the specified fields and makes those fields available for the expression that is evaluated and returned for the value of the switch expression.

See also https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/406

This could be re-written as:

```
int eval(Expr n) {
    if (n instanceof IntExp ie) {
        return ie.i;
    }
    if (n instanceof NegExpr ne) {
        return -eval(ne.e);
    }
    if (n instanceof AddExp ae) {
        return eval(ae.left) + eval(ae.right);
    }
    if (n instanceof MulExpr me) {
        return eval(me.left) * eval(me.right);
    }
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(n);
}
```